# How to constraint maximum length of keys of an object in JSON schema

Tags: jsonschema

I would like to constraint maximum length of a key of the property which type is `object`. All of its values are generated in runtime and I'd like to spot a misbehavior as soon as possible by validating document before further processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "Object with 10 char max properties",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "minProperties": 1,
    "patternProperties": 
    {
        "^[a-z]{0,10}$": 
        { 
            "description": "Some description", 
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! Assuming I want to reuse it with multiple properties of various types, how would I do that?

Comment: You can remove 'type': 'string' line and thus you will allow any type, not just strings.